# Certificates with invalid serial no. (iPhone has denied the launch request.)

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Please read through before marking it as a duplicate.

- on 2019-03-06, apple came out with a statement about how they have
  issued certificates with invalid serial nos. because of the EJBCA
  issue. read more:
  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1533655
- while they claimed to have resolved the issue, I tried deleting my
  developer certificate from the system and with Auto-signing disabled 
  in Xcode.
- After, I enabled auto-signing so as the have a new certificated
  created. to my surprise, I didn't help and I still continue to
  struggle as I cant launch my app on my phone and debugger attachment 
  fails.
- I know the workaround is to check the `ask on launch box` in edit
  schema. but, that's a tedious process and want to able to smoothly
  launch my app and be able to debug.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please read through once more. I don't believe it has been answered. The issue has in-fact popped up just about a week ago !

Comment: There are numerous questions at the moment all relating to the same issue.  I have closed this as a duplicate of the most active one.

Comment: @Paulw11 With all due respect, That question was asked 5 months ago before the certificates were invalidated. Also all the answers point to kind of solution, rather workarounds that I have already mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Paulw11 I got why you marked it duplicate with the above stated question. sorry to bother you and Thanks !

Comment: @AppleCiderGuy I have the same problem as you. I even tried to create another session and the problem still persists. I wonder if this is not related with the "free" account for Apple Developer? It's been 4 days that I looked for the solution and still nothing ...